# Making divided main-test structure for a java project by hand

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, project

The target is to create the following classic project structure:
[image]

I mean mainly the folders structure that divides work classes from test classes.

I can do it easily creating a Maven project and removing the Maven nature. The problem is that I want to use this convenient structure in the Eclipse without installed Maven plugin.

But if I try to create a new project and to build the same structure in it by hand, it always does something else, but not what I want. I have tried Package explorer, Project Explorer, Navigator, creating new Folder, new package, new source folder, even copying the structures from an already *good* project - all in vain. It glues pieces of packages or sources names together, or refuses to do the action, or uses only parts of the names. Changing the created folders and packages won't help, either. Obviously, eclipse is somehow mixing the names in the package line with the names in the directories' hierarchy.

So, how can I create a hierarchical directory structure in a project and references to the same package in some of these directories? Of course, it **is** possible, for the Maven plugin does it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `New > Java Project` fill in the first page and then click `Next >` for the second page. Make sure the `Source` tab is selected. Click `src` in the tree and click `Remove source folder 'src' from build path`. Then click `Create new source folder` and enter `src/main/java`, repeat to create the `src/test/java` folder.

You can also do this on the `Properties > Java Build Path > Source tab`.

Comment: Excellent! THank you for the possibility to change the structure of the existing project